# how to automate ant time picker using selenium web driver and java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ant-design-pro, testautomationfx

In my application, there are few ant time pickers(https://ant.design/components/time-picker/) used in the forms. I'm experiencing the following behavior,

"OK" button of the start time is working properly.
[image]

using the below coding part,

```
shiftStartHrs.click();
    shiftStartHrs.sendKeys(starttime);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(shiftStartOkBtn).perform();
    shiftStartOkBtn.click();
```

But the end-time selection is not working,
[image]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Mention the steps to get to `Shift plan`.

Comment: shiftEndHrs.click();
shiftEndHrs.sendKeys(endtime);
Thread.sleep(3000);
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(shiftEndOkBtn).perform();
shiftEndOkBtn.click();

Comment: What I meant was, in the Website, which were the buttons that we need to click so that we are able to see `Shift plan`. There are so many options.

Comment: we just need to click on the shift - end field then time dropdown will appear.